# A few Webdriver IO Mocha Chai questions

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js, chai, webdriver-io

I am new to using the webdriver-io with Mocha and Chai. First of all here is my script:

```
var homePage = 'http://www.mypage.com';
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var headerText = 'h1.browse-header-title';
var currentHeaderText;
var links = ['Furniture','Fine Art','Jewelry & Watches','Fashion'];

describe('Test Suite 1', function(){

    before(function(){
       console.log('Running navigation h1 tag suite');
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        browser.close();
        // What method do I use?
    });

    it('Should click Furniture and page header should match', function(done){
       browser.url(homePage).click('a[data-tn="global-nav-item-link-furniture"]');
        currentHeaderText = browser.getText(headerText);
        expect(currentHeaderText).to.equal(links[0]);
        console.log('h1 tag is '+currentHeaderText+'');
    });
    it('Should click Fine Art and page header should match', function(done){
        browser.url(homePage).click('a[data-tn="global-nav-item-link-fine-art"]');
        currentHeaderText = browser.getText(headerText);
        expect(currentHeaderText).to.equal(links[1]);
        console.log('h1 tag is '+currentHeaderText+'');

    });
    it('Should click Jewelry & Watches and page header should match', function(done){
        browser.url(homePage).click('a[data-tn="global-nav-item-link-jewelry-&-watches"]');
        currentHeaderText = browser.getText(headerText);
        expect(currentHeaderText).to.equal(links[2]);
        console.log('h1 tag is '+currentHeaderText+'');
    });
    it('Should click Fashion and page header should match', function(done){
        browser.url(homePage).click('a[data-tn="global-nav-item-link-fashion"]');
        currentHeaderText = browser.getText(headerText);
        expect(currentHeaderText).to.equal(links[3]);
        console.log('h1 tag is '+currentHeaderText+'');
    });

});
```

My first question is, is there a better place to store the variables and a proper method to call them?

When running the afterEach browser.close() function, what is the best way to reset the browser session, I tried browser.reset() but when calling the second test it didn't seem to work properly. Is there a better way with mocha and chai to close the browser, reset the session and open the browser and go to the home page?

These were the requirements I was given:

1) The test must be written in mocha with assertions using chai. The
framework used to drive the tests must be webdriverIO – no native selenium commands.

2) The test should be written in a way that utilizes a page object pattern

3) Variables that would likely be used in other tests (such as a user
email/password) should be stored separately from the test file.

Answer (score 1):

For storing the variables outside of the code, there are several ways.

1. You could leverage wdio.conf.js and start adding customConfig object like [this](http://webdriverio-examples/googleSearch_tests/config/local/wdio.conf.js)
   and use them in the code `_page.navigate(browser.options.customConfig.baseUrl);` like [this](http://webdriverio-examples/googleSearch_tests/specs/tests/google_search_test.js)
2. Or keep it in a separate .json file, use [nconf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nconf) to bring into your test code
3. Or simply import data.json like import testdata from './testdata.json' and use them directly

as far as the browser.close(), requirement, if its a workflow, series of user actions, I would keep them in one file to run them on one browser session. 
If these are unrelated tests, separate specs and let wdio/mocha handle parallel execution and browser sessions for you.